# How do I make a regex with a lookbehind assertion that still works at the start of a string

Tags: java, regex, lookbehind

I need to emulate the behavior of `\b` at the start of a string, where I'm adding additional characters to the set that count as a word boundary. Right now I'm using something like:

```
"(?<=\\W|\\p{InCJKUnifiedIdeographs})foo"
```

This works as I would like, *unless* I'm at the start of the string being matched: in which case the assertion fails and I don't get a hit. What I want is the equivalent of *match if I'm at the start of the string or `foo` is preceded by a non-word character or an ideograph.* But I can't get the right incantation to support that.

Any thoughts? Or is this impossible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by match if i am at the start of the string? That would capture all strings because all strings have a 'start of string'

Comment: It doesn't: if I use the aforementioned regex against the string "foo foobar baz" it will *not* find 'foo' because the look behind fails.

Comment: In most cases, you can get what you want by reversing the condition:    `(?<![\w\P{InCJKUnifiedIdeographs}])`. I'd add it as an answer, but I don't have time to test it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
"(?<=^|\\W|\\p{InCJKUnifiedIdeographs})foo"
```

Just add the start-of-string anchor to the lookbehind conditions.

Comment: Thanks Robert, that works like a charm. Somehow in the various combinations I experimented with I didn't try the most obvious.

Comment: Adding a carot leads to error in my case `((?<=^| )is(?= |$)` https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/21

Comment: @СашкоЛихенко That's a limitation of Python's regex engine. It allows only "fixed width" look-behinds, and the length of `^` (zero/null?/NaN?) is obviously different than ` ` (one).

Comment: @СашкоЛихенко See if using the word-boundary match will work for you, e.g. `\bis\b` or something like that.

Comment: Thanks, this was not very easy to find in documents... I tried variants like `(?<=\\^|\\W...` or `(?<=(\\^|\\W...` etc.